# Android App Installing "Application Not Installed"

Tags: android, installed-applications

I am trying to install and app. I developed it and signed it and exported it and when I go install on phone it comes up with "Application not installed".

No the application has not been installed before and I need to remove it.
No debug mode is not true

Here is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="spending.tracker"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".SpendingActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ListExspenses" />
    <activity android:name=".GraphExpenses" />

</application>
```

Comment: How are you installing the APK onto your device? I would recommend using appInstaller or the like from the app market, if you are not already doing so.

Comment: I tried using the file explorer that was shipped with my Samsung S2. Click the APK-file, it pops up but in the end it says "Application not installed" with a green "check" to the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate a new apk file with a fresh new keystore.

Comment: I Tried to generate a new APK file with new Keystore. Still didnt work.

Comment: What version of android are you using on real device?

Comment: Im having the same problem... can intall from Eclipse, but not from an apk-file...